# Realm deleting valid object raises "Attempted to access detached row" error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, realm

I am trying to delete objects from realm database in a winForm dotnet application, but my code gives me this error

> Exception thrown: 'Realms.Exceptions.RealmInvalidObjectException' in
>   Realm.dll An exception of type
>   'Realms.Exceptions.RealmInvalidObjectException' occurred in Realm.dll
>   but was not handled in user code Attempted to access detached row

```
Realm realm;
IQueryable<RObj> items;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var config = new RealmConfiguration("DB.realm");
        config.ShouldDeleteIfMigrationNeeded = true;
        realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
        //WriteRealmTest();
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        items = realm.All<RObj>();

        listboxMain.DisplayMember = "title";
        listboxMain.ValueMember = "id";


        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = items;
        listboxMain.DataSource = bs;

    }

private void listboxMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            int index = listboxMain.SelectedIndex;
            if (index < 0) { return; }
            RObj item = items.ElementAt(index);
            if (!item.IsValid)
                return;
            using (var trans = realm.BeginWrite())
            {
                realm.Remove(item);
                trans.Commit();            //when this line is commented, no error is raised
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, this is for future reference for anyone facing the same problem

I had first to remove the item from the `BindingSource` before removing it from the realm database

Adding `bs.RemoveAt(index)` before `using (var trans = realm.BeginWrite())` solved the issue